# When does the Alien Die reset?

Tags: xcom

I understand the concept of what the Alien Die does.  Every time someone rolls for something, they check the Alien Die against the current threat level.  If the threat is 1, the Alien Die indicates a failure on 1 or less.

What I don't know is when that die resets.  For example:

I'm the Science Officer and I am researching Tech 1 (since you have to go in order from 1 to 3).  I roll once and get 1 success.  I need three.  I press my luck and increase the threat.  I roll again and get one more success.  Now comes my question.

If the Alien Die ends up greater than the threat and I stop, what happens to the threat when I go to the next research item?
If the Alien Die ends up greater than the threat and I keep going, and then I succeed, what happens to the threat when I go to the next research item?
If the Alien Die ends up less than or equal to the threat, what happens to the threat when I go to the next research item?

This applies to Base Defense, Global Defense, and Missions as well.  What happens per continent, per alien, and per mission task?  I don't know if the threat ever resets itself during those times.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The alien die resets between tasks.  The only exceptions are that you don't reset between mission tasks, and you don't reset between base defense tasks.

You reset between each science task and each global defense task, so you'll start each science card and each continent at 1.  For missions and base defense, you start the first one at 1, but from then on it will keep increasing until you move to the next type of task.

Comment: For the purposes of Threat: Each Research ("I", "II" and "III") is a separate Task, Orbital Defense is a single Task, all of Global Defense is a single Task, all of Base Defense (no matter how many enemies that involves) is a single Task, and all of a Mission (including the Final Mission) is a single Task.

Comment: @David You are close, but you got Global Defense wrong.  Each continent is a separate task.